# Casting through extension method

Tags: c#, .net, casting, lambda, resharper

It was bothering me that there's so many places in code that follow this pattern:

```
int amount = 100;
Person person = new Employee();

var em = person as Employee;
if (em != null)
{
em.IncreaseSalary(amount);
}
```

So I created a small extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void IfAssignable<T>(this object source, Action<T> run) where T : class
    {
        var target = source as T;
        if (target != null)
        {
            run(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I could do:

```
        int amount = 100;
        Person person = new Employee();

        person.IfAssignable<Employee>(e => e.IncreaseSalary(amount));

        amount = 10;
```

I like this because it is more compact and e goes out of scope: I wouldn't be using it anyway if it were null.

Resharper then warns "access to modified closure". This is because the value of "amount" might change before the call gets executed I believe.

I don't think this is actually the case, since the code is executed synchronously directly. Am I missing something here? The fix to copy to a temporary value before executing "IncreaseSalary" defeats the purpose of the extension.

Edit: Clarification; I (believe I) know what this warning is trying to say. If I'd be executing code later (meaning asynchronously, or subscribing to an event) and use one of the values passed in implicitly from the outer scope, the warning would be right.

Additionally, this extension method is meant to be generic. I realize I could add any amount of extension methods to cater for any amount and types of parameters (pass them explicitly instead), pass those in through the method signature, and make this work. The idea behind the extension method is to be generically applicable though (except for asynchronous calls, event subscribtions, but that applies to all lambda's).

Comment: Your `IfAssignable` *could* store `run` somewhere else instead of simply directly invoking it. If it were to do that, `run` could be invoked later, and if invoked later, it would see the changed amount. From a C# perspective, your code is perfectly valid and will do what you want. But I don't have Resharper, so I cannot give a useful answer that tells you how you can rewrite this so you don't get a warning.

Comment: I had tried storing run in a temporary value within the extension already, no luck.

Comment: You could stop reusing variables. This would have the added benefit of making it easier to reason about your program's behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper is correct to warn you about you possibly modifying a captured variable, because it doesn't know what what you're doing with your lambda. In your case, the lambda is executed immediately, so there are no side effects from modifying the parameter.

Which is why you can instruct ReSharper that your lambda expression is immediately handled, by using the `[InstantHandle]` [code annotation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Annotations_in_Source_Code.html) attribute, by applying it on your `Action<T>` parameter:

```
public static void IfAssignable<T>(this object source, 
                                   [InstantHandle] Action<T> run) where T : class
{
    var target = source as T;
    if (target != null)
    {
        run(target);
    }
}
```

And the warning will disappear!

You will need to add the code annotations file to your project. You can do this by going into ReSharper Options, then select Code Inspection → Code Annotations. Press the **Copy default implementation to clipboard**, and paste the contents into a new file. If you change the namespace of the annotation attributes (default is `JetBrains.Annotations`, you will need to add the new namespace to the settings in the Code Annotations page in Options.

Comment: Thanks Igal, this is exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid it by using additional 'state' parameter:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void IfAssignable<T, TState>(this object source, Action<T, TState> run, TState state) where T : class
    {
        var target = source as T;
        if (target != null)
        {
            run(target, state);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it that way:

```
    int amount = 100;
    Person person = new Employee();

    person.IfAssignable<Employee>((e, amount_) => e.IncreaseSalary(amount_), amount);

    amount = 10;
```

That's also a way to avoid type/memory leaks and other strange bugs.

Comment: This works, but I had meant the extension method to be generically applicable. The employee/person example with a single integer to pass in was meant as an example. the idea was any amount of variables might be passed in. Since the code executes synchronously I think this should not be a problem. Could you explain what you mean by type/memory bugs?

Comment: First you can generalize this for any amount of parameters, for example by using a custom struct as the TState parameter.

Second, I've talked about two leaks and possible bugs: 1. As the delegate holds a reference to all the referenced parameters, they cannot be garbage-collected until the delegate is dead (of course it is not applicable for the synchronous case). 2. Type leak - when referencing a variable out of the delegate scope the compiler is forced to create an anonymous class which enlarge your program size. 3. In addition strange bugs of unexpected variable change may happen.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the question to state what I am looking for. The idea of defining a custom struct beats the purpose of the extension method; it requires more code, I was looking to reduce/beautify code by making the check for null and resulting action into single call, rather than having it span multiple calls.